# text-selection in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change text-selection on my HTML page. I want to change the hex value in css for the selected text whenever i select some text from para. How can i do that in CSS ?

For example as shown in this image below it is changing color to cyan.

[image]

Is it possible to do ? if So How ? any field in CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement to what Reinies wrote and for future issues: You could get FireBug and right-click on the element and select "Inspect Element". That will provide you with the exact code you need.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it is highly browser-specific.  Please see [CSS > selection styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html).

Comment: I'm looking for cross-browser, so that it looks same from all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>

    ::-moz-selection {
    color:white;
    background:#3A75AF ;
    }

    ::selection {
    color:white;
    background:#3A75AF ;
    }

    </style>
```

Will do your job. Works in majority browsers. Dont ask me about IE.