# selected text background color

Tags: css

when i use any site i see that selected text background color show blue or according our OS theme.can i change this selected text background color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [text-selection in CSS ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461285/text-selection-in-css)

Comment: @KennyTM i have try to find this but i didn't find so i ask this and thanks for find this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this style. this will work on all major browser except IE

```
<style>
             ::-moz-selection
            {
             background:#0C0;
             color:#f00;
             }
            ::selection
            {
            background:#6374AB;
            color:#F00;
           }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can apply CSS styles to `::-moz-selection`.
In Safari, you can apply CSS styles to `::selection`.

See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html).